# JAVA: size of frame and centering graphical objects

Tags: java, frame, centering

Is there anything obvious wrong with this line of code? I want rectangle to stay centered regardless the size of the window. But this don´t work for some reason, the rectangle stays the same place.

```
    public void run() {
    setSize(800, 800);
    createEntireFigure();


}
private void createEntireFigure(){
    int centerOfWindowWidth = getWidth() / 2;
    int centerOfWindowHeight = getHeight() / 2;

    GRectWithGLabel ("A String",centerOfWindowWidth, centerOfWindowHeight); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rectangle size code is only called on rectangle creation, and so it makes sense that the rectangle's position will not change if the GUI is re-sized. You need to somehow listen for size changes in your GUI and call code to re-position the rectangle then for this to work. What graphics library are you using?

Comment: acm.Graphics - it´s a library specific for students, I am following the programming methodology classes made available by Stanford.

Comment: @Tom: OK, many of us here will not be familiar with this library since it is not part of core Java, but again, understand that you're setting variables in your createEntireFigure method, but that these variables once set are not smart and will only change if you tell them to change. To have them changed when the window is re-sized, you must somehow listen for re-size events, and then reset these variables when this happens.